# How can I divide an image into two specific polygons?

Tags: image, opencv, object, detection, region

I have an image shown in Image 1.

Now I want to detect humans in the picture, more specifically, where they are located.

I create two or more polygons in an image (as shown the Image 2) and I want to find regions of detected humans.

Take the following example:
Let's suppose that I have 5 detected humans in the image and then I need to find how many of them are in region 1 and how many of them are in region 2.
I have coordinates of detected humans, and I built an algorithm to compare coordinates of the regions and detected humans' coordinates.

Am I approaching the problem correctly? Is there a better approach?
Edit : I am using OpenCv in Python

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCkdc.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p60X.png)

Comment: You should specify the technology being used or the one that you need to use.

Comment: beside comparing coordinates, you can create binary image for each region and just check the value of new set of binary images at person coordinates . I think this should be faster. But how are you defining your region? Using contours coordinates right?

Comment: Huh? There aren't any humans in your picture.